# ClassFormatException io.qameta.allure.aspects.StepsAspects: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to run a testng test using Spring for dependency injection. The dependency resolution is working as expected, but the console is full of log messages such as:

> org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor error SEVERE:
>   register definition failed
>   org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File:
>   'io.qameta.allure.aspects.StepsAspects': Invalid byte tag in constant
>   pool: 18  at
>   org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:261)
>     at
>   org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:162)
>     at
>   org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:288)
>     at
>   org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:369)
>     at
>   org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:338)
>     at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:97)
>     at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:378)
>     at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:271)     at
>   org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryAspect(BcelWeaver.java:163)

Certain methods contain the annotation `@Step` which is used for generating details in an Allure report (the step annotation is in the `io.qameta.allure` package).

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I resolve the issue being identified in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `pom.xml` file under:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
```

it contained the node:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Copying and pasting this dependency to the main `<dependencies>` node in `/project/dependencies` resolved the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to get \@Step tag working for few days.